# angular default sidenav not selected at initial load

Tags: angular, typescript

Here I want to load `basic` page of the `sidenav` in the initial load of the  `sidenav`.
Here is the `routing.ts` which will load the sidenav

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { MapGuard } from 'src/app/shared/guards/map.guard';
import { CampaignReportsComponent } from './campaign-reports.component';

  const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: CampaignReportsComponent,
    data: { breadcrumb: 'Campaign-report' },
    redirectTo:'/basic',
    children: [
      {
        path: 'type',
        loadChildren:
          './campaign-reports-type/campaign-reports-type.module#CampaignReportsTypeModule',
        canActivate: [MapGuard],
        data: { breadcrumb: 'Type' }
      },
      {
        path: 'basic',
        loadChildren:
          './campaign-reports-basic/campaign-reports-basic.module#CampaignReportsBasicModule',
        data: { breadcrumb: 'Basic' }
      },


 {
    path: 'activity',
    loadChildren:
      './campaign-reports-activity/campaign-reports-activity.module#CampaignReportsActivityModule',
    data: { breadcrumb: 'Activity' }
  },
  {
    path: 'rewards',
    loadChildren:
      './campaign-reports-rewards/campaign-reports-rewards.module#CampaignReportsRewardsModule',
    data: { breadcrumb: 'Rewards' }
  },



         {
            path: 'winners',
            loadChildren:
              './campaign-reports-winners/campaign-reports-winners.module#CampaignReportsWinnersModule',
            data: { breadcrumb: 'Winners' }
          }
        ]
      }
    ];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class CampaignReportsRoutingModule {}
```

But it will give this error 
`Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'basic'`

What should be done in here?..Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your routes, as you are trying to call /basic directly, you need to write outside the children array or add blank path which will redirect to basic

```
 const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: CampaignReportsComponent,
    data: { breadcrumb: 'Campaign-report' }, 
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo:'/basic',
      },
      {
        path: 'type',
        loadChildren:
          './campaign-reports-type/campaign-reports-type.module#CampaignReportsTypeModule',
        canActivate: [MapGuard],
        data: { breadcrumb: 'Type' }
      },
      {
        path: 'basic',
        loadChildren:
          './campaign-reports-basic/campaign-reports-basic.module#CampaignReportsBasicModule',
        data: { breadcrumb: 'Basic' }
      },
     {
        path: 'activity',
       loadChildren:
          './campaign-reports-activity/campaign-reports- 
       activity.module#CampaignReportsActivityModule',
       data: { breadcrumb: 'Activity' }
     },
     {
        path: 'rewards',
        loadChildren:
        './campaign-reports-rewards/campaign-reports- 
        rewards.module#CampaignReportsRewardsModule',
         data: { breadcrumb: 'Rewards' }
      }, 
         {
            path: 'winners',
            loadChildren:
              './campaign-reports-winners/campaign-reports-winners.module#CampaignReportsWinnersModule',
            data: { breadcrumb: 'Winners' }
          }
        ]
      }
    ];
```